# How to add listView inside cardView android?

Tags: android, listview, material-design, android-cardview

Forgive me for any mistakes. I'm a beginner.
Can anyone please explain how to create a listview inside a cardview layout in android. Example settings app in android 6.0
[image]
I wanna create a scrollable cardview layout with listview items in each cardview layout.
I have searched enough online and nothing seems to help me.
If you have any solution this it would be helpful for me.

Comment: This can be done using scrollview and inside it put your components as per your requirements.

Comment: go through  this link:-http://javapapers.com/android/android-cards-list-view/

Comment: What is the problem to use ListView inside FrameLayout (CardView is actually FrameLayout)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a `RecyclerView` with a vertical `LinearLayoutManager` (which will look the the same as a `ListView` but with better performance) and a fixed size inside your `CardView`. The xml for your `CardView` will look something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and then programmatically set fixed size on your `RecyclerView` to true, set the LayoutManager and create a custom RecyclerView.Adapter to fill the RecyclerView's rows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, dataSet);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The cardView is a backgroud of the listView. So the item of this will like: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2N8C.png)

Hope to help you!