# Xamarin - RecyclerView with PagerSlidingTabStrip - System.NullReferenceException in SetLayoutManager()

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I try to use a RecyclerView in a SlideMenu.

I use this example for my SlideMenu : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android

And now, I add RecyclerView with SlideMenu. I need two menu : "menu" and "product", so I use two xml file for my fragment : menu.xml for "menu" and menu_recyclerView.xml for "product".

This is my code :

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
  <include
    android:id="@+id/top_menu"
    layout="@layout/top_menu"/>
  <com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
      android:background="@color/Blue"
      app:pstsDividerWidth="1dp"
      app:pstsDividerPadding="12dp"
      app:pstsDividerColor="#50FFFFFF"
      android:textColor="@color/Green"
      app:pstsTextColorSelected="@color/White"
      app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/Red"
      app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/White"/>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_recyclerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/menu_recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_recyclerView is a pattern for my items

row_recyclerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingRight="15dp"
      android:paddingLeft="15dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#000000"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="88"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="7dp"
      android:paddingBottom="7dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Brand"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtBrand"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

-

```
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
{
    protected override int LayoutResource
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.Layout.Main;
        }
    }

    private Android.Widget.Toolbar _topMenu;
    private Adapter _adapter;
    private ViewPager _pager;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip _tabs;

    private RecyclerView _recyclerView;
    private LayoutManager _layoutManager;

    public string _tag = "MainActivity";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
        _layoutManager = new LayoutManager(this, _recyclerView);

        _layoutManager.addItem("one", "two", "three");
        _layoutManager.addItem("one", "two", "three");

        _layoutManager.createLayoutManager();

        _adapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        _pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
        _tabs = FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip>(Resource.Id.tabs);

        _pager.Adapter = _adapter;
        _tabs.SetViewPager(_pager);
        _topMenu = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.top_menu);
        SetActionBar(_topMenu);
    }
```

-

```
class LayoutManager
{
    public RecyclerView _mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager _mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter _mAdapter;
    public ItemList<Item> _mItems;
    public Activity _main;
    public LayoutManager(Activity main, RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        _main = main;
        _mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        _mItems = new ItemList<Item>();
    }
    public void createLayoutManager()
    {
        _mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(_main);
        _mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(_mLayoutManager);
        _mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(_mItems, _mRecyclerView);
        _mItems.Adapter = _mAdapter;
        _mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(_mAdapter);
    }
    public void addItem(string name, string brand, string description)
    {
        _mItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Img = Resource.Drawable.Icon,
            Name = name,
            Brand = brand,
            Desciption = description
        });
    }
}
```

And in this line (in my LayoutManager.cs):

```
_mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(_mLayoutManager);
```

I have This error :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I do not understand what is the value of the probleme ?
I forget any thing ? 
I am completely lost ?
Please.. help !

Thanks you,
Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code: `public class MainActivity : BaseActivity` and

```cs
protected override int LayoutResource
{
    get
    {
        return Resource.Layout.Main;
    }
}
```

I guess that your `BaseActivity` is the same as [BaseActivity.cs of PagerSlidingTabStrip sample](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android/blob/master/Sample/BaseActivity.cs).

Then you actually here set your `Main.xml` as the content view of your `MainActivity`, and in this `Main.xml`, there is no `RecyclerView` with the id `recyclerView`, it is in your `menu_recyclerView.xml`. Although you can find the id `recyclerView` when you coding, but it is not present on the content view.

So in your `MainActivity`, when you try to find it using `_recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);`, this `_recyclerView` here should be null when you run your code. Then of course when you call `_layoutManager = new LayoutManager(this, _recyclerView);`, you pass a null to this `LayoutManager`. You can insert a break point on this line to check if it is a null:

```
_recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
```

To solve your issue, I think you may need to redesign your layout or your frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer !
Yes my BaseActivity il the same as [BaseActivity.cs of PagerSlidingTabStrip sample.](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android/blob/master/Sample/BaseActivity.cs)

I follow your advice, and yes I have a probleme with my architecture.
I learn how it works the RecyclerView, and I add this :

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

  <include
    android:id="@+id/top_menu"
    layout="@layout/top_menu"/>

  <com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

      app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
      android:background="@color/Blue"

      app:pstsDividerWidth="1dp"
      app:pstsDividerPadding="12dp"
      app:pstsDividerColor="#50FFFFFF"

      android:textColor="@color/Green"
      app:pstsTextColorSelected="@color/White"

      app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/Red"
      app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/White"/>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <include
    layout="@layout/recyclerView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

menu_recyclerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingRight="15dp"
      android:paddingLeft="15dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:civ_border_width="2dp"
          app:civ_border_color="#000000"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="88"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="7dp"
      android:paddingBottom="7dp">
      <TextView
          android:text="Name"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txtName"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:textSize="18sp" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Brand"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txtBrand"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:singleLine="true" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Description"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:textSize="16sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I add the new xml file : recyclerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now I call `recyclerView.xml` in my `Main.xml`. `recyclerView.xml` contain CardView, and he wrap RecyclerView.

I should put my RecyclerView in a only CardView or I should to wrap my `menu_recyclerView.xml` with cardView ?

I want to create a menu like this :

[image]

I have a result, but now I think I have a probleme with my `menu_recyclerView.xml` because I don't have a list, juste "name, brand, description". screenshot :

[image]

I search for this, and is a another subject...

I think the good keyword for this probleme is : RecyclerView, CardView
for finish this is my other sources :

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

[How to add listView inside cardView android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406901/how-to-add-listview-inside-cardview-android)

[How to implement RecyclerView with CardView rows in a Fragment with TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579614/how-to-implement-recyclerview-with-cardview-rows-in-a-fragment-with-tablayout)

Thanks a lot,